# CSS div style not working in HTML

Tags: html, css, border

I am trying to apply borders to few DIVs in my webpage using the following CSS:

```
.column-left{ float: left; width: 20%;}
.column-right{ float: right; width: 20%; visible:false;}
.column-center{ display: inline-block; width: 60%;}

a:link, a:visited {
    background-color: #f44336;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
}

a:hover, a:active {
    background-color: red;
}

#test{         margin-left:auto;
               margin-right:auto;
               margin-top:0px;
               margin-bottom:0px;
               border-style:solid;
               border-left:1px;
               border-right:1px;
               border-top:0px;
               border-bottom:1px;
               border-color:#000000;    
               background-color: yellow;
}
```

having in my html something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cols.css">
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
   <div class="column-center">...</div>
   <div class="column-left"><a href="#"> Link 1 </a><br><a href="#"> Link 2 </a><br><a href="#"> Link 3 </a><br><a href="#"> Link 4 </a><br>
</div>
   <div class="column-right"> ... </div>
</div><div id="test"> ... </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Settings in #test do not work and I cannot figure out the reason. Any ideas?

Edit: it works correctly if I put properties of #test in another CSS file.
Edit: adding relevant HTML code.

Comment: Where's the html that matches your anchor and column classes?

Comment: plz provide jsfiddle to get useful answers :)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3):

your border-style property should be next of all border properties:
example :

```
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
margin-top:0px;
margin-bottom:0px;
border-left:1px;
border-right:1px;
border-top:0px;
border-bottom:1px;
height: 100px;
border-style:solid;
border-color:#000000;    
background-color: yellow;
```

and is better use shorthand value :

```
margin:0 auto;
height: 100px;
border:1px solid #000;
border-top:0;
background: rgb(255,255,0);
```